# Speech Synthesis in C#

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I use the speech synthesis for a simple program, and I was 
wondering if there is supporting in other languages than english?

I want that the speech will be in the local language. Is it possible?

Comment: No you can't the .net framework support only English language you can try with third party programs but you must pay for the licence. For example there is Dragon

Comment: If he is using System.Speech, there is indeed support for multiple languages available. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SpeechSynthesizer.GetInstalledVoices` to obtain a list of all available voices, together with some Culture Information. On my Windows 8.1 machine, there is a German and an English language installed. You should be able to check if there is a capable voice present with the GetInstalledVoices method.

[Here is a list of the supported languages on the Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378476%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I checked and i have one installed voice - english. Where can i find it in hebrew ? The sdk 11 doesn't support the hebrew language

Comment: [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224) is the download page for the supported voice. I'm afraid you are out of luck for the Hebrew language, though. If you need Hebrew you'll have to look for a third party solution. [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hebtts/) is what I found with a quick google search...